# How to use magento site in Phonegap

Tags: web-services, magento, cordova, sencha-touch

I am new in phonegap. is it possible to create link between Phonegap and Magento
i want to  show my shopping website using phonegap

Comment: What do you mean by a link between Phonegap and Magento? A Magento based website can be viewed by a smartphone browser. By picking some small screen friendly Magento themes, your site's users should be able to navigate and use the website. What functionality are you looking to add using Phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: **NO**. Besides many million reasons why nobody did it so far, think that iOS and Android don't run PHP by default, so there is no way to reuse PHP code. You need to build a layer in Magento that will provide data through API(s) and a totally new Phonegap codebase on top of that. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question but I still want to give my 2 cents. Maybe it is useful for someone else later.

I think it should be easily possible.

The simplest way is to create a responsive design for your magento shop and then run this website inside the phonegap / cordova web container.

You can also combine this approach with the more clean approach of writing a javascript and html5 based clients which connects via API.